# Compare string with velocity

Tags: velocity, string-comparison

Considering the following piece of code in a velocity template:

```
#set($brandName = $player.brand.name)
#set($brandNameExample = "NameExample")

#if($brandName == $brandNameExample)
    11111
#else
    22222
#end
```

I always get `22222`. Of course, `player.brand.name = "NameExample"`.

Can anybody explain me why and how to get it work please?

Comment: From the [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html) page, they provide the following example - #if( $foo == $bar)it's true!#{else}it's not!#end</li>. Do you need the leading hash?

Comment: @MrMoose : Thanks for your reply but unfortunately the hash did not help.

Comment: could you please post real example, I want to be sure you added # everywhere. Did you try #if($brandName == "NameExample") and then #if("NameExample" == $brandNameExample)

Comment: Maybe output player.brand.name with a character at the beginning and end so you can check if there are any leading or trailing spaces or something similar.

Comment: I made it I do not see any leading or trailing character

Comment: When I do $player.brand.name I can see the correct value ("NameExample"), when I do if(!$player.brand.name) I can see that the object player is null ! Any idea why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution : I called twice to velocity : the first time without the player object and second one with it. So at the first call all directives concerning player could not be evaluated and returned null. Thank you all for your help

Comment: @I need some help on the same. Can you please help on the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308655/equals-functionality-not-working-in-velocity-macro link

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to test this

```
#set($brandName = "NameExample")
#set($brandNameExample = "NameExample")
#if($brandName == $brandNameExample)
11111
#else
22222
#end
```

if it works then I would try to output $player, $player.brand, $player.brand.name
you need to make sure that $player.brand.name - keeps correct value.
- case sensivity?
- sure that spell '$player.brand.name' correctly?

I think you simply has problem in object $player

Comment: I tried this and it works. But in my example it still does not. While debugging I saw that my player object contains a brand object that is lazy-loaded. But anyway when I check the parameters I give to velocity everything is here so I don't really understand.

Comment: I forgot to say that from the beggining when I display $player.brand.name I get the correct value ! :) The problem seems to occur only when comparing.

Comment: what if you try $brandName.equals($player.brand.name) ?

Comment: I tried everything : $player.brand.name gives me the good value but when I compare I get false. Here is another test I made that failed : 
$player.getBrand().getName().equals("NameExample")

#if($player.getBrand().getName().equals("NameExample"))
11111
#else
22222
#end

I get :

true

22222

... I will try with the brand id instead of the name :)

Comment: I think that your test worked because "NameExample" is the same string used for both variables brandName and brandNameExample so the address is the same that is why == gives true.

Comment: Can we check equalsIgnoreCase in VTL ?

Answer (score 2):

First add it to your Context (see the official doc: [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#the-context)):

```
context.put("StringUtils", StringUtils.class);
```

Then you can call **StringUtils.equals()** method from your Velocity template:

```
#if($StringUtils.equals($brandName, $brandNameExample))
    ## logic here...
#end
```