# Equals functionality not working in velocity macro

Tags: macros, velocity

Can I know what I am making wrong in the below velocity macro code.
I have followed the below link. Still now luck.
https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.4/user-guide.html

```
    #macro( ccase $profiles,$databasename )
    #foreach( $profile in $profiles.split(',')) 
    #if( $profile == $databasename)
    #set($result = $profile)
    #$result
    #end
    #end
    #end

    #set($databaseName="sql")
    #set($sqlDatabase = "#ccase( $profile-db,$databaseName )" )
    #if($sqlDatabase == "sql") <!-- Fails Here  This is not getting passed at all-->
     Below code notexecuted
    #end
```

Comment: Which version of Velocity are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When the condition is satisfied, as in when `profile-db` contains `sql` as one of the entries, the value that gets assigned to the `sqlDatabase` variable is not just `sql`, but it is `#sql` with leading and trailing spaces. If the condition `$sqlDatabase == "sql"` is changed to something like `$sqlDatabase.trim() && $sqlDatabase.trim().substring(1) == "sql"`, to remove the spaces and the leading `#`, it should work. Complete modified template below:

```
#macro( ccase $profiles $databasename )
    #foreach( $profile in $profiles.split(',')) 
        #if( $profile == $databasename)
            #set($result = $profile)
            #$result
        #end
    #end
#end

#set($databaseName="sql")
#set($sqlDatabase = "#ccase( $profile_db $databaseName )" )
#if($sqlDatabase.trim() && $sqlDatabase.trim().substring(1) == "sql")
     Below code notexecuted
#end
```

Tested with Velocity 2.3 using a [velocity-tester](https://velocity-template-tester.onrender.com/) that I created.